# android, get pixel size of screen?

Tags: android, resolution

I am making an app for a tablet which has a resolution of 1280 x 800, and I want custome graphics for it. But when i took a screenshot of the screen the resolution was 1024x600, why is this? What size background image would I make?!

Comment: doesn't make sense. what is your device ?

Comment: galaxy tab 2 10.1, weird. It appears to be working sometimes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentionned here : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html
if you want the pixel of your screen, you can write

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
```

and then, you can call :

```
int width = metrics.widthPixels;
int height = metrics.heightPixels;
```

Answer (score 1):

in the simulator it is actually resized to fit your screen and takes in your screens resolutions nothing wrong with your code or images.

Comment: I dont use an emulator, I use a device.

Answer (score 1):

Screen shot dimension maynot be same as resolution.

```
you need to make graphics with 1280 x 800.
```

screen shot taken depend on theway how it is created,it doesnt have to be same resolution as display.